# Input problems for trigonometric table generator

Tags: c++

1. The trigonometric function(s) chosen (A. sine, B. cosine, C. tangent).
2. The unit of angle (A. degree or B. radian)
3. The starting value and ending values for the angle
4. The increment from one angle value to the next

These are my current task. Currently I'm trying to do , for example, if I choose sine - A, then i wanted to choose degree - A, how to prevent these 2 from clashing? Im still new in c++ so I'm still confused on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. It's my first post here so, forgive me if i did anything wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

const double PI = 3.14159265;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double v1, v2 , i;
    cout << "Trigonometric Table Generator" << endl;
    cout << " Choose the trignometric function(s): A-Sine, B-Cosine, C-Tangent" << endl;
    cout << " (e.g Enter A for Sine or AC for both Sine and Tangent): ";
    char input1;
    cin >> input1;


    cout << " Choose the unit of angle : A - degree or B - radian(e.g Enter A for degree) ";
    char input2;
    cin >> input2;

    if (input2 = 'A') {

        double degrees,i;
        degrees = (PI / 180)* i;
    }

    else if (input2 == 'B') {

        double radians, i;
        radians = ( 180 / PI)* i;

    }

    cout << "Enter the starting value and ending values for the angle, separated with a space: ";
    cin >> v1 >> v2;

    cout << "Enter the increment from one angle value to the next: ";
    cin >> i;



    switch (input1) {

    case 'A':

        double sine;

        for (i = 0; i <= v2; i = i + v1) {

            //degrees
            sine = (PI / 180)* i;

            cout << i << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << sine << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Grab some basic first . And see this [link](https://notesformsc.org/c-program-to-convert-radian-to-degree/)  . Let me know , what you are looking for.

Comment: What does `cin >> i;` and then `for (i = 0; ...` do?

Comment: @Md.MokammalHossenFarnan thanks for the link. it does have the basics of what i need for my project. thanks alot !

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin cin>>i; is the increment of value . so for example if I entered v1 = 0 , v2 = 180 , i=10 , it will increment by 10.

Comment: Oh, I thought you read `i` to hold the increment and then turned around and reset it to `i = 0` at the start of the `for` loop losing the increment value you had just read. No? Maybe chose another name for your increment variable, like `double increment;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this the old fashion way and let the compiler help us. Let's start with your code unchanged. Let's compile with **warnings enabled** so we see if the compiler will point out any potential problems for us. We enable warnings for gcc/clang by including (at minimum) `-Wall -Wextra` (and for new C programmers, we should probably include `-pedantic -Wshadow` as well), with VS, use `/W3`. So let's try compiling your code:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=gnu++11 -Ofast -o trigtable trigtable.cpp
```

On windows in the *VS Developers Command Prompt* creating the executable `trigtable.exe`:

```
cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /Fetrigtable /Tp trigtable.cpp
```

Oh no. The compiler says:

```
trigtable.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
trigtable.cpp:23:21: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     if (input2 = 'A') {
                     ^
trigtable.cpp:25:24: warning: declaration of ‘i’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
         double degrees,i;
                        ^
trigtable.cpp:11:21: warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
     double v1, v2 , i;
                     ^
trigtable.cpp:25:16: warning: variable ‘degrees’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         double degrees,i;
                ^
trigtable.cpp:31:25: warning: declaration of ‘i’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
         double radians, i;
                         ^
trigtable.cpp:11:21: warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
     double v1, v2 , i;
                     ^
trigtable.cpp:31:16: warning: variable ‘radians’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         double radians, i;
```

So on line `23` we forgot that `=` is an assignment, and `==` is a comparison. fixed.

Next on line `25` the `-Wshadow` warning picked up the fact that the variable `i` we were using on line `25` **shadows** the declaration of `i` on line `11`. Let's fix that by changing the declaration on line `11` to use a descriptive name of `increment` instead of `i`.

Next on line `25` we set the variable `degrees` (and the same for `radians` at line `31`), but neither are used in you program, huh? Oh, since we declare `degrees` within the *block-scope* of `if (input2 == 'A') {...}`, it is only usable within that block and goes *out-of-scope* as soon as that block ends. (the same applies to `radians` with `if (input2 == 'B')`).

Further, in both cases, since we have not initialize `i` taken any input to set it, `degrees = (PI / 180)* i;` would invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to use `i` while it contained an indeterminate value.

What is `i` there anyway? Oh, it is the beginning value of `increment`. But we haven't set that either. Let's make this `i`, `increment` and move our read of `increment` above this block of code... In fact, let's move all our input above our calculations. If any of our input is invalid, it will make the calculations meaningless anyway. Let's also move the declaration for `radians` and `degrees` to the top of `main()` so they survive for the entire duration of the program.

Making just those changes and adding a quick compiler check to only cause `system ("pause");` if running on windows (it's not needed otherwise), your code could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

const double PI = 3.14159265;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double v1, v2 , increment, degrees, radians;
    char input1, input2;

    v1 = v2 = increment = degrees = radians = 0.0;  /* initialize values */

    cout <<  "Trigonometric Table Generator" << endl
         << " Select function(s): A-Sine, B-Cosine, C-Tangent" << endl
         << " (e.g Enter A for Sine or AC for both Sine and Tangent): ";

    if (!(cin >> input1)) { /* validate EVERY user input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input for 'input1'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << " Unit of angle : (A - degree, B - radian): ";

    if (!(cin >> input2)) { /* validate EVERY user input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input for 'input2'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Starting and ending angle values ("
         << ((input2 == 'A') ? "degrees" : "radians") << "): ";
    if (!(cin >> v1 >> v2)) { /* validate EVERY user input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input for 'v1 or v2'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Enter the angle increment("
         << ((input2 == 'A') ? "degrees" : "radians") << "): ";
    if (!(cin >> increment)) {  /* validate EVERY user input */
        cerr << "error: invalid input for 'increment'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (input2 == 'A')
        degrees = (PI / 180.0) * increment;
    else if (input2 == 'B')
        radians = (180.0 / PI) * increment;

    switch (input1) {

        case 'A':
            double sine;

            for (double i = v1; i <= v2; i += increment) {

                //degrees
                sine = (PI / 180.0) * i;

                cout << i << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << sine << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'B':
            cerr << "case 'B' not implemented\n";
            return 1;
            break;      /* technically not required, but good form */
        default : 
            cerr << "error: invalid function selection\n";
            return 1;
            break; 
    }
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    system("pause");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling again, even with full warnings enabled -- now warnings and no errors. Now we have confidence that at least the code should operate without rudimentary errors.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trigtable
Trigonometric Table Generator
 Select function(s): A-Sine, B-Cosine, C-Tangent
 (e.g Enter A for Sine or AC for both Sine and Tangent): A
 Unit of angle : (A - degree, B - radian): A
Starting and ending angle values (degrees): 30 45
Enter the angle increment(degrees): 1
30     0.524
31     0.541
32     0.559
33     0.576
34     0.593
35     0.611
36     0.628
37     0.646
38     0.663
39     0.681
40     0.698
41     0.716
42     0.733
43      0.75
44     0.768
45     0.785
```

Ummm, wait `"30     0.524"` is **wrong**. The `sin(30 degrees)` is `0.5` not `0.524`. Let's check our calculation... `sine = (PI / 180.0) * i;` -- that's not right, that's just a conversion from degrees to radians. What if we change that line to:

```
                sine = sin((PI / 180.0) * i);
```

**Corrected Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trigtable
Trigonometric Table Generator
 Select function(s): A-Sine, B-Cosine, C-Tangent
 (e.g Enter A for Sine or AC for both Sine and Tangent): A
 Unit of angle : (A - degree, B - radian): A
Starting and ending angle values (degrees): 30 45
Enter the angle increment(degrees): 1
30       0.5
31     0.515
32      0.53
33     0.545
34     0.559
35     0.574
36     0.588
37     0.602
38     0.616
39     0.629
40     0.643
41     0.656
42     0.669
43     0.682
44     0.695
45     0.707
```

That's better.

There are a number of further improvements you need to make. Starting with ***using descriptive variable names***. What does `input1` and `input2` or `v1` and `v2` mean any way? Why not `trigfuncs` for `input1` and `unitangle` for `input2` and `anglestart` for `v1` and `angleend` for `v2`. (makes a heck of a lot more sense when you are another 100 lines down in your code).

I've provided a few additional comments inline above. Read them. Also note, these are just minimum, minor changes needed to get your code to compile and calculate the `sin` values correctly, much additional work should be done. The way you are taking input `'A'` for degrees, `'B'` for radians and then using separate `degrees` and `radians` variables is a bit *wonky*. Just prepare the code to compute everything taking the angle and increment in radians, and then if degrees is selected, just make the conversion. You don't really need a `switch` to handle the separate cases, what would logically flow a bit easier is a loop over the characters in `input1` and a `switch` on the character for which function to compute and then within that a check on whether `v1, v2` and `increment` are in radians or degrees. Those are just a few thoughts, the remainder of the implementation is left to you.

If you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: oh my...this...is it . thank you so much for time and help! couldnt thank you enough!

Comment: v1 = v2 = increment = degrees = radians = 0.0;  /* initialize values */ why do you have to initialize the value =0? wouldnt the value would automatically starts from 0 unless we input some value to it?

Comment: In C++ if you do not initialize a variable its value will not necessarily be 0, it could be anything.

Comment: Correct. If a variable is not initialized it's value is *indeterminate*, and you inadvertently attempt to access it - you invoke *Undefined Behavior* and the defined (reliable) execution of your code ceases at that point. Undefined behavior can be anything from appearing to complete correctly, to SegFaulting. So when you are learning, a good habit is to initialize variables when they are declared. The `v1 = v2 = ..` chain is just to save space. No magic to it. Personally I would just declare each variable on its own line and initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ideas to get you on the right track here:

First, in C++ (as in most other programming languages), you must assign to a variable *before* you use its value. For example:

```
double radians, i;
radians = ( 180 / PI)* i;
```

Since you have used `i` in an expression before you assigned it a value, this will result in undefined behavior. Instead, try moving the expression `radians = ( 180 / PI)* i;` inside of the for loop where `i` has been assigned.

Second, in C++ variables have scope determined generally by the brackets `{}` that they are defined inside. So when you write something like:

```
if (input2 = 'A') {

    double degrees,i;
    degrees = (PI / 180)* i;
}
```

then the variables `degrees` and `i` exist only inside the if statement. Even if you define another variable with the same name, it will not actually be the same variable if it is in a different scope.

Finally, you'll want to think carefully about what mathematical operations you are performing here. For instance, it doesn't seem like you've actually called the `sin` function anywhere. In C++, functions are called by using the name followed by the arguments in parenthesis. So for instance, `sin(3)` returns the sine of 3.

This stuff can be pretty tricky when you're new to C++, so don't get discouraged! You might want to ask a teacher or friend for help, they'll be able to give much more personalized help to guide you through the process.